# Rad Studio C++ builder missing VCL headers

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I downloaded Embarcadero [C++Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/downloads/) to compile an pre-existing project I was given.  When I try to build, it says it cannot find `vcl/Classes.hpp`.  I have searched my computer for the file, but it does niit appear to be there.

Where can I go download this library to be able to build this project?  There does not seem to be any links on Embarcadero's website to download missing libraries.

Comment: It's on my machine, in the `%PROGRAMFILES%\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Include\Windows\RTL` folder (the version of C++Builder that comes with RAD Studio XE2), same folder (except in `8.0` version) for XE, and in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Include\vcl` for the version that comes with RAD Studio 2010. It appears that something may have gone wrong with your installation. What version of C++Builder did you download?

Comment: I just downloaded the trial, the about screen tells me it is Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2 Version 16.0.4358.45540

Comment: That should match the first folder location I gave you then. I don't have any experience with the trial versions, so I don't know what's included and what's not. I'd think the VCL header files would be there, though, if for nothing else but type definitions. You could open a free [support](http://support.embarcadero.com) case with Embarcadero, though, since this seems like it could be an installation problem. If it's not, they can at least tell you that the files aren't included in the trial version. Maybe someone else will jump in here that is more familiar with the trial version limits.

Comment: Looking through it, it seems that the include directories were out of date, probably set in an old install.  I had to update the include directories in the project, your comment led me to the solution, so if you wanna post it as the answer I can accept it

Comment: Done. I'll clean up the comments in a bit to reduce the clutter. Glad you got it sorted out. :)

Comment: @DanF : could u elaborate the steps u followed to update include directories(mentioned above by u in comment)? even i m facing a similar problem where many *.hpp files are not getting refferred in the project...

Comment: @Abhinav Unfortunately, I no longer work at the company where I had this issue and do not remember the specific resolution steps I took

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on my machine, in the `%PROGRAMFILES%\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Include\Windows\RTL` folder (the version of C++Builder that comes with RAD Studio XE2), same folder (except in 8.0 version) for XE, and in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Include\vcl` for the version that comes with RAD Studio 2010. It appears that something may have gone wrong with your installation.

Per comments, you downloaded the `XE2` trial version, which means you should find it in the first folder I listed above; if they're not there, you either have a problem with your installation or the headers aren't included in the trial. (I'd think they would be for type definitions at least, so I suspect the install.)

You could open a free [support case](http://support.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero, though, since this seems like it could be an installation problem. If it's not, they can at least tell you that the files aren't included in the trial version.